# Prevent a function from being called twice in a row

Tags: python, decorator

I'm learning decorators and I have a task asking me to create a decorator to prevent a function from being called twice in a row. If the same function is called again, it should return None
I can't seem to understand how it really works, so far I've achieved this:

```
def dont_run_twice(f):
    global counter
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        counter += 1
        if counter == 2:

            return None
        else:
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            return result

counter = 0
```

(I know that it's a really bad attempt, but I just don't know a way to keep track of a function called with specific arguments in order to check if it was already before)
the output should be something like:

```
@dont_run_twice
def myPrint(*args):
    print(*args)

myPrint("Hello")
myPrint("Hello")  #won't do anything (only return None)
myPrint("Hello")  #still does nothing.
myPrint("Goodbye")  #will work
myPrint("Hello")  #will work
```

Comment: What is the comment about "specific arguments"? Do you wish to treat `myPrint('a')` and `myPrint('b')` as different?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want

Comment: Using `global` will give the wrong result here when the decorator is applied to more than one function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this can help you:

```
import functools


def do_not_run_twice(func):
    prev_call = None

    @functools.wraps(func) # It is good practice to use this decorator for decorators
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal prev_call

        if (args, kwargs) == prev_call:
            return None
        prev_call = args, kwargs
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Try this:

```
my_print("Hello")
my_print("Hello")  # won't do anything (only return None)
my_print("Hello")  # still does nothing.
my_print("Goodbye")  # will work
my_print("Hello")  # will work.
```

Comment: Actually I want the last my_print("Hello") to work, the function shouldn't be called twice in a row, not twice

Comment: no, you can not use set because your args can be not hashable. try my_print([]) with using set, it will be error

Comment: @MM1 I have changed my answer

Comment: This doesn't support keywords. Would be best to use a tuple of `(args, kwargs)` to check the previous call parameters instead of just `args`.

Comment: This is the first time I've heard of `nonlocal` after all these years.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which is very similar to Andrey Berenda's solution, but which works by assigning an attribute to the function object, rather than using a non-local variable. The practical difference is that the function's previous arguments become available externally, which might help for debugging purposes.

```py
from functools import wraps

def dont_run_twice(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if (args, kwargs) == wrapper._prev_args:
            return None
        wrapper._prev_args = args, kwargs
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapper._prev_args = None
    return wrapper
```

Example:

```py
>>> @dont_run_twice
... def f(x, y):
...     return x + y
... 
>>> f(1, 2)
3
>>> f(3, 4)
7
>>> f(3, 4) # returns None
>>> f(1, 2)
3
>>> f._prev_args
((1, 2), {})
```

Note that both solutions have a slight flaw: you can call with the same argument values if you provide them as positional arguments then keyword arguments (or vice-versa):

```py
>>> f(5, 6)
11
>>> f(x=5, y=6)
11
```

As a workaround, you can declare the wrapped function with positional-only (or keyword-only) arguments:

```py
# positional-only, requires Python 3.8+
@dont_run_twice
def f(x, y, /):
    return x + y

# keyword-only
@dont_run_twice
def g(*, x, y):
    return x + y
```

Note also that if the previous args are mutable, then strange things can happen:

```py
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4]
>>> f(a, b)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a[:] = [5, 6]
>>> b[:] = [7, 8]
>>> f([5, 6], [7, 8]) # returns None
```

The second function call here returns `None` despite the new arguments not being equal to the original arguments by either value or identity; they are equal to the original arguments' *current* values which were changed after they were used as arguments. This could lead to rather subtle bugs, but unfortunately there's no easy way to fix it.