# Prevent calling a function more than once if the parameters have been used before

Tags: python, memoization

I would like a way to limit the calling of a function to once per values of parameters.

For example

```
def unique_func(x):
    return x

>>> unique_func([1])
[1]
>>> unique_func([1])
*** wont return anything ***
>>> unique_func([2])
[2]
```

Any suggestions? I've looked into using memoization but not established a solution just yet.

This is not solved by the suggested [Prevent a function from being called twice in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811637/prevent-a-function-from-being-called-twice-in-a-row#59812097) since that only solves when the *previous* func call had them parameters.

Comment: Why would you want to do *nothing*? Memoization lets you remember what the function returned last time, and return it again without having to do the work to recompute it. You could maintain your own cache of inputs and return `None` explicitly if the same input is seen again, but again: what's the use case?

Comment: @chepner the function being called will publish something, so we only want it to publish when the parameters haven't been published before

Comment: So the function isn't being called for its return value in the first place, but just for its side effect?

Comment: @chepner yes exactly

Comment: @kaya3 that answer does not solve this problem as it only prevents when the previous call had the same result - we want this to be unique calls per session

Comment: I see. What type are the arguments going to be - in your example it's a list of numbers (or a list with just one number?), is that so for the real use-case?

Comment: @kaya3 real use case is 1 string

Comment: Consider using the built-in [`functools.lru_cache()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memoization uses a mapping of arguments to return values. Here, you just want a mapping of arguments to `None`, which can be handled with a simple set.

```
def idempotize(f):
    cache = set()
    def _(x):
        if x in cache:
            return
        cache.add(x)
        return f(x)
    return _


@idempotize
def unique_fun(x):
    ...
```

With some care, this can be generalized to handle functions with multiple arguments, as long as they are hashable.

```
def idempotize(f):
    cache = set()
    def _(*args, **kwargs):
        k = (args, frozenset(kwargs.items()))
        if k in cache:
            return
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return _
```

Comment: the solution for multiple args doesn't seem to work (when using strings for example)

Comment: Hm, it did at least have a problem with the order of the keyword arguments not being ignored. That should be fixed; do you have a different example that fails?

Comment: (There's also a corner case involving passing the default value explicitly for a parameter with a default value: given `def foo(x=3):...`, `foo(3)` and `foo()` would be treated as different calls. I'm not motivated enough to fix that. Like I said, handling multiple arguments requires some care.)

Comment: (And the default value issue is present even with a single parameter, as you can see.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the built-in [`functools.lru_cache()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) instead of rolling your own.

It won't return nothing on the second function call with the same arugments (it will return the same thing as the first function call) but maybe you can live with that. It would seem like a negligible price to pay, compared to the advantages of using something that's maintained as part of the standard library.

Requires your argument `x` to be hashable, so won't work with lists. Strings are fine.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def unique_fun(x):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I've built a function decorator to handle this scenario, that limits function calls to the same function in a given timeframe.

You can directly use it via PyPI with `pip install ofunctions.threading` or checkout the [github sources](https://github.com/netinvent/ofunctions/tree/master/ofunctions/threading).

Example: I want to limit calls to the same function with the same parameters to one call per 10 seconds:

```
from ofunctions.threading import no_flood

@no_flood(10)
def my_function():
    print("It's me, the function")

for _ in range(0, 5):
    my_function()

# Will print the text only once.
```

if after 10 seconds the function is called again, we'll allow a new execution, but will prevent any other execution for the next 10 seconds.

By default `@no_flood` will limit function calls with the same parameter, so that calling `func(1)` and `func(2)` are still allowed concurrently.

The `@no_flood` decorator can also limit all function calls to a given function regardless of it's parameters:

```
from ofunctions.threading import no_flood

@no_flood(10, False)
def my_function(var):
    print("It's me, function number {}".format(var))

for i in range(0, 5):
    my_function(i)

# Will only print function text once
```